# Accidentally installed Python 2.7 on CentOS

Tags: centos, python

I need newer Python so I downloaded .tar.gz from the site, unpacked, run `./configure; make; make altinstall`. I had then separate Python 2.7 and default 2.5 and all worked fine.

But recently I needed to recompile Python with new libraries and instead of `make altinstall` I run `make install`. That replaced CentOS Python 2.5 with 2.7. I made symbolic link from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.5` but when I run `python` then Python 2.7 is started.

I wonder if what I done is bad for my system or I could live with it. Do I need to revert 2.5 as default? yum seems working fine.

Comment: Try `which python` to see what is actually run if you type `python`.

Comment: @RobWouters It's `/usr/local/bin/python` and it's 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your statement:

```
I wonder if what I done is bad for my system or I could live with it.
Do I need to revert 2.5 as default? yum seems working fine.
```

This should not affect you system. The only effect is that you may have is the confusion when using python. For the system and package manager (yum), this should not be an issue.